# Will 'Find My Mac' work after my Macbook Pro has been locked due to failed login attempts?

Tags: macbook-pro, security, find-my-mac

My late 2013 Macbook Pro was stolen a week ago and I've been tracking it with 'Find My Mac'. The thief would turn the laptop on for a few minutes at a time in the evenings and probably try a few passwords.

A few days ago, I went into FMM and it said that my Macbook was locked. I can only assume that it was due to failed login attempts because I didn't remotely lock it or erase it. Since being locked,  it hasn't been online in FMM. Can it still connect to wifi/icloud when locked? All options except "Play Sound" are greyed-out in FMM.

Comment: Just out of interest, why did you not take any action?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD because I didn't want to tip off the thief to the fact that I was tracking them. I basically know where the laptop is but it's an apartment building and the police won't help. So I'm trying to narrow in.

Comment: Bad move, usually when they know to be watched they run or surrender :), Send a message anyway, something like, you are been watched! This is your last chance to return it or more serious action will follow. Offer a email or phone number where you can be reached for returning. It does not has to be face to face, the thief can place it somewhere and call you to pick it up. Offer small reward ($20).

Comment: @Buscar웃SD Yeah, it was a gamble. I'll send a message if it comes online again...